# Removing row shading and horizontal lines in DT::datatable

Tags: r, datatable, formatting, dt

I would like to remove the row shading and horizontal lines that automatically appear when calling DT::datatable.

It seems that this link has some information, but I am unfamiliar with HTML and CSS and cannot get it working. https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes

`DT::datatable(iris)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `stripe` argument in `class` to false, all the lines inside the table and the shading will disapear.

```
DT::datatable(iris,
              class = list(stripe = FALSE))
```